# Printing truncated columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, printing

I have a dataframe with some rather long column values and would like them truncated when printing, so that it only prints the first 10 or 20 characters. This is the dataframe:

[image]

As you can see the trip_id is very long and shifts the other columns into the next row.
Does someone know how to print this DF so that the trip_id will get shortened? I only found questions asking how to print *non*-truncated dataframes. I guess there is some option in the pd.option_context but I coulnd't find it yet.

Here's my printing code:

```
with pd.option_context('expand_frame_repr', True):
    print(f"Trips_with_service_days (mit Fahrplantagen)")
    print(f"{trips_with_service_days.head()[['trip_id', 'service_id', 'start_date', 'end_date', 'fahrplantage_ohne_ausfaelle']]}")
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you want to change the `display.max_colwidth` option?

Comment: Thank you, did the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @Simone in the comment for the answer. The display.max_colwidth option does what I wanted. New code:

```
pd.set_option("max_colwidth", 35)
with pd.option_context('expand_frame_repr', True):
    print(f"Trips_with_service_days (mit Fahrplantagen)")
    print(f"{trips_with_service_days.head()[['trip_id', 'service_id', 'start_date', 'end_date', 'fahrplantage_ohne_ausfaelle']]}")
```